# SpringBoot parse URI query

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote a class, I try to send a request:
URL: http://localhost:8080/?Name=%F8%FA

but I get an error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse URI query
```

Code:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

@RequestMapping(value = "/*",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String getName(
        @RequestParam(name = "Name", required = false) String name
 ) {
    return name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: If possible can you please paste request method code also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I tried and it's working

Spring boot main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);         
    }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getName(@RequestParam(name = "Name", required = false) String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: @bulbasour111 : Please "Mark as Answer" on the post If it helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

**I have found this solution which is working for me:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getName(HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String url = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "Windows-1251");
```